# Запись csv строки в базу данных PostgreSQL при помощи Python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

Пытаюсь записать csv строку в базу данных PostgreSQL при помощи Python. Строку (lines) получаю из интернета.

Вид строки из интернета: ['[MSNG],5,06/10/21,10:00:00,2.2970000,2.3120000,2.2970000,2.3120000,161000',...]

Привожу строку к следующему виду(с помощью кода см.ниже): ['[MSNG]', '5', '06/10/21', '10:00:00', '2.2970000', '2.3120000', '2.2970000', '2.3120000', '161000',...]

Код: '''

```
query = ",".join('?' * len(lines[0].split(",")))
    query = '({0})'.format(query)
    query = ",".join([query] * len(lines))
    query = 'INSERT INTO fin VALUES ' + query
    lines = ",".join(lines).split(",")
    print(lines)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, lines)
    cursor.commit()
```

'''

Ошибка:

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: ",") LINE 1: INSERT INTO fin VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,...
^
[image: Таблица БД]

Comment: Ну вы же какую-то ерунду пишете в query. вы после каждого изменения query выводите ее на печать. сами увидите, что получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена.

Не так:

```
INSERT INTO fin VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Для PostgreSQL применяется:

```
INSERT INTO fin VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

```
lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
        query = ",".join(("%s" for _ in range(len(lines[0]))))
        # print(query)
        query = f'INSERT INTO get_finance ("TICKER", "PER", "DATE", "TIME", "OPEN", "HIGH", "LOW", "CLOSE", "VOL") VALUES({query}) '
        # print(repr(query))
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(query, lines)
        connection.commit()
```

Код был изменен из-за использования другой таблицы (query).

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис INSERT выглядит так

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Поскольку вы не указываете столбцы, то для вас он такой

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

в вашем случае в query будет что то типа такого

```
INSERT INTO fin VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ['[MSNG]', '5', '06/10/21', '10:00:00', '2.2970000', '2.3120000', '2.2970000', '2.3120000', '161000']
```

В этом есть две проблемы

1. Перечисление Columns не обязательно, можно его убрать
2. Values должны быт ьв круглых скобках

Собственно предлагаю два варианта:

```
# Вариант с сырым запросом
query = f"INSERT INTO fin VALUES ({lines[0]})"
print(query)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.commit()
```

или

```
# Вариант с подстановкой через $
query = ", ".join([f"${i + 1}" for i in range(len(lines[0].split(",")))])
query = f"INSERT INTO fin VALUES ({query})"
lines = ",".join(lines).split(",")
print(query)
print(lines)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, lines)
cursor.commit()
```

Но глобально код тяжело читается, не рекомендую такое использовать в продакшене - только для личных скриптов/лабараторных и тд